# how to insert yoast main category in advanced custom fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields, yoast

I want to use yoast's main category when building blocks in advanced custom fields

```
        //Primary Yoast Category
        $primaryCat = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_ID());
        $primaryCat = $primaryCat->get_primary_term();


        $catPrimaryName = get_cat_name($primaryCat);
        $catPrimaryLink = get_category_link($primaryCat);
        $context['catPrimaryLink'] = $catPrimaryLink;
        $context['catPrimaryName'] = $catPrimaryName;

// ----------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (is_array($modules['categories']))
        add_filter('block_categories', function ($categories, $post) use ($modules) {
            $module_categories = [];
            foreach ($modules['categories'] as $module_category)
                $module_categories[] = [
                    'slug' => $this->block_category_slug . '_' . $module_category,
                    'title' => $this->block_category_title . ' - ' . $module_category
                ];

            return array_merge($module_categories, $categories);
        }, 10, 2);

    // add our blocks & fields
    foreach ($modules['modules'] as $block) {
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name' => $block['name'],
            'title' => __($block['title']),
            'description' => __($block['description']),
            'render_callback' => [$this, 'my_acf_block_render_callback'],
            'category' => $this->block_category_slug . '_' . $block['category'],
            'icon' => 'layout',
            'align' => 'wide',
            'keywords' => array_merge($this->default_keywords, isset($block['keywords']) && is_array($block['keywords']) ? $block['keywords'] : []),
        ));
```